# How do I prepend 1. 2. 3. to a list using Javascript

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I have a page that looks like this:

```
<div class="post">
     <h1>Foo Bar</h1>
</div>
```

I want to add post number through javascript.

```
<div class="post">
     <h1>1. Foo</h1>
</div>

<div class="post">
     <h1>2. Bar</h1>
</div>
```

I want to do this usign jQuery, and I supposed I could loop through **each** post and just add a count using prepend, doing something like this:

```
$('.post h1').each( function(num) { 
    this.prepend(num+' .'); 
});
```

The error I am getting is:

```
**Object #<HTMLHeadingElement> has no method 'prepend'**
```

I was wondering if anyone can take a look at the code and tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the callback, `this` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Note that the index is zero based, so you should add one to it:

```
$('.post h1').each( function(num) { 
  $(this).prepend((num + 1) + ' .'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the jQuery operator on `this`:

```
$(this).prepend(num+' .');
```